# Node GM (GraphicsMagick) - Loop based image generation

Tags: node.js, loops, imagemagick, gm

Using GM (GraphicsMagick) in NodeJS I wanted to generate some image content via using loops with commands such as drawPoint to set pixel data however i am not sure on the best practice to do so.

The code i have tested with loops works however it is very slow since it loads and saves the image each time it sets a pixel.

Here is my test which generates random rgb noise. How can i temporarily store image data which is set via a loop and then save it only after it has finished?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});

var w = 200;
var h = 200;

gm(200, 200, '#ddff99f3').write('./Random Noise.png', function (err) {});

var row = 0;
var col = 0;

var r = 0;
var g = 0;
var b = 0;

function rgb(r, g, b){
  r = Math.floor(r);
  g = Math.floor(g);
  b = Math.floor(b);
  return ['rgb(',r,',',g,',',b,')'].join('');
}

for (row = 0; row < h; row++){
    for (col = 0; col < w; col++){

        r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
        g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
        b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);

        gm('./Random Noise.png')
        .fill(rgb(r,g,b))
        .drawPoint(col, row)
        .write('./Random Noise.png', function (err) {});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about node.js's gm to offer any answers, so this is more of an open comment to get you on the right path.

1. Use [FX expressions](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php)

   Faster then your solution, but still slow as each pixel will need to be evaluated.

   ```
   convert -size 200x200 xc:'#ddff99f3' -fx 'rand()' 'Random Noise.png'
   ```
2. Build a raster image first.

   It's way faster to populate 1d array of 8-bit values, and import them directly. Again, you'll have to checkout node-gm documents to see how they import/export data.

   ```js
   var raster = [],
       index = 0;
   for (row = 0; row < h; row++){
      for (col = 0; col < w; col++) {
         raster[index++] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1) // RED
         raster[index++] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1) // GREEN
         raster[index++] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1) // BLUE
      }
   }
   ```

   The CLI command to import this would be something like ...

   ```
   cat raster.dat | convert -size 200x200 -depth 8 rgb:- 'Random Noise.png'
   ```

   I imagine the docs would refer to the above as "streams" and "pipes".

Hopefully someone else would be able to offer node-gm examples.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the -fx command doesn't seem to be available however. The command list is posted here: https://github.com/aheckmann/gm

Comment: -fx is an Imagemagick command and may not be available in GraphicsMagick. I do not use GraphicsMagick, so cannot say for sure, but it might be there listed with a slightly different name. Another approach, might be to create your background image and then use -draw (Imagemagick) with a list of points to insert at different locations.